# How to use Monolog bundle in symfony2?

Tags: symfony, monolog

I want to be able to log errors to dev.log or app.log in my code but I have not been able to see a basic example on how to get it done. Any pointers? I did Google it.

Comment: http://symfony.com/doc/master/cookbook/logging/index.html